# Android ExpandableListView or List Adaptor

Tags: android, android-listview

Android phone app.  I will describe the situation and then pose my question afterwards.

I want to give the user the ability to pick an option from an expandable list, but when an option that has sub options (children), I want to just display those child's option(s).  So.. not the normal functionality for the Expandable ListView list.

So... instead of "expanding" and showing a list, only the items from the sub-menu/list would be displayed.

Example list

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3 >
---- Sub Item 1 for Item 3 (Item 6)
---- Sub Item 2 for Item 3 (Item 7)
---- Sub Item 3 for Item 3 (Item 8) >
     -------- Item 9
     -------- Item 10
Item 4
Item 5

In the above example, the user would initially see Items 1 to 5.  If any of an items from this top list are selected (user touches it).. except for Item 3, you are done... selection made.

If Item 3 is selected... then a Sub list of items for item 3 is shown... just Items 6,7,8.. I want Items 1 through 5 to no longer show on the screen.

If Item 8 is then chosen, only Items 9 and 10 would be on the screen for the choices.

Is an Expandable ListView the way to go or maybe a List Adaptor? or something else.?

I have searched for hours to see something similar.  Any possible solutions are appreciated.  I do not mind doing hours of legwork, just stuck and need direction.

A bonus would be to show a ">" symbol to the right of a choice that has sub choices under it.  I have tried to show this for items 3 and 8.

I appreciate your time in reading this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> If Item 3 is selected... then a Sub list of items for item 3 is shown... just Items 6,7,8.. I want Items 1 through 5 to no longer show on the screen.

In your case ListAdapter will solve your problem. Since you want `list of one Kind` at a time on the screen.

Here, by `list of one kind` i mean you are either showing `Item <itemnumber>` or their `subitem <subitemnumber>`.

When you will click the item 3, you should have a way to know which all items are child of clicked item. By getting the list of all the child items. You set that list as a datasource for the adapter and notify the adapter that data set has changed.

P.S:
Though it is not related to your question and business requirement, if your list is not too long (including the list of the child of the item), then you should think of Expandable listView with an additional functionality that every child is visible all the time, or you can say expandable listview without collapse functionality(i.e always expand). This way user can access/see every element all the time.